# using udev rules create and remove device node on a kernel module load and unload

Tags: linux, kernel-module, udev

trying to figure out the udev rules that can automatically create a device node when I insert a particular kernel module and remove the device node when the kernel module is removed.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww, thank you for your feedback. Actually my question does not involve the programming/scripting directly but the answer does. In future I will keep that in mind and put the question in the form that it does not look like a dev ops question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explored the udev rules in detail and with the help of udevadm tool I am able to derive the following udev rules, my kernel module name is "amdtPwrProf".

On ACTION=="add" the device node is created and on ACTION=="remove" that device node is removed.

```
 # Create the device file when the module is inserted.

 SUBSYSTEM=="module", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="amdtPwrProf", RUN+="/opt/codexl/amdtPwrProf_mknod.sh"


 # Remove the device file when the module is removed.

 SUBSYSTEM=="module", ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="amdtPwrProf", RUN+="/bin/rm /dev/amdtPwrProf"
```

The contents of script "amdtPwrProf_mknod.sh" are,

```
mknod /dev/amdtPwrProf -m 666 c `cat /proc/amdtPwrProf/device` 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn how udev work

Try to add a script:

```
cat >/path/to/myscript  <<"eof"
#!/bin/sh

newfile=`mktemp /tmp/udev-test-XXXXXXXXXX`
echo "$0 -- $@" >$newfile
set >>$newfile
eof
chmod +x /path/to/myscript
```

Then (as root)

```
echo >/etc/udev/rules.d/99-myscript.rules 'RUN+="/path/to/myscript"'

service udev restart
```

Then try to add/remove devices and look at `/tmp/udev-test-*`

... read `man udev`, look other files in `/etc/udev/rules.d` and build your own script, by refining contidions of your personal rule.

Comment: thank you for your comment, yes I am already aware about the basics of udev and udev rules but was mainly interested to solve a particular scenario. And was able to find the solution after digging more into it.